# Cant get current_user Device and oAuth facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, device

I am signing in users only from facebook with Omniauth

** Users::OmniauthCallbackController**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController <
```

Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

```
def facebook
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if 
     is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end

def failure
  redirect_to games_path
end
```

end

but when i try to get current_user to another contoller it always returns nil.

I have read that devise has a built in function for current_user but that didn t seem to work properly(also returned nil every single time) so i implemented another method.

**current_user helper**

```
before_action :define_current_user
def current_user
  User.find_by id: session["current_user_id"]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

How can i make it work?

**User.rb**

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :team

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable,  :rememberable, :trackable,:validatable 
 ,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]



 def self.new_with_session(params,session)
    super.tap do |user|
     if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && 
     session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
            user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
   end
 end

 #Saving new user to the database 
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do|user|
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.name = auth.info.name
       user.image = auth.info.avatar
       user.save!
    end     
 end
end
```

Comment: Did you add `before_action :authenticate_user!` callback to needed controllers? After it you can get value of default 'current_user' from Devise

Comment: thanks that worked!! Can i ask something else i cant retrieve user image with user.image = auth.info.avatar . is this correct?

Comment: What is the `image` field in the User model? Try `user.image = URI.parse(auth.info.image) if auth.info.image?` (I don't remember why, but in the my old project it is auth.info.image, maybe facebook changed field name from `image` to `avatar`). Please, accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: Ok . that didnt work with image i will try with avatar . Is type text . Should i change that?

Comment: You need to use any of image uploaders for `user.image`. Read about Carrierwave, Shrine or built-in ROR ActiveStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` callback to needed controllers. In this case you'll be able to get value of default `current_user` from Devise